# Is this a IE10 BUG? ASP .NET MVC3 + HTML5 + IE10 Preview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I wrote a little test project with asp.net MVC3 and HTML5.
Maybe I am stupid or I found a bug in the preview of Internet Explorer 10.

The testcase:

Create an asp.net MVC3 Project as an Internet Application with VS2010.
Open the index file and write a html5 section attribute with some text inside into the file and save it.
Add an ID to the section and set a background color in site.css to it.
Start the app. Everything will work fine. You will see the text and the section has the color you defined.
Now create an Account go to the LogOn Page und do a login.
In my case the section no longer has the color I defined - really strange.
After pressing F5 the color was back again.

I looked in the source code and everything seemed to be okay, there was a section in it but after a little research I found out that in the debugger the HTML code wasn't okay.
The Problem is: After calling a MVC3 RedirectToAction Method (that is what happens when you do a login), the IE10 can not handle the section attribute anymore. It doesn't exist in the source code of the integrated debugger.
I tried the Code in all other new Browsers and it works perfectly.

It would be very nice if someone could test and check if the problem is me or the browser.

Comment: Solution: stop testing in a browser that nobody is supposed to use for general browsing, unless you're actually dedicating your time to alpha/beta testing Internet Explorer.

Comment: Normally I agree to that. But it would be awesome if I could use the latest HTML5 features of IE 10 for a prototype that I code for my thesis ;)

Comment: Doesn't Chrome / FF support HTML5?  Why are you bothering messing with IE10?

Answer (score 3):

Of course there are bugs in IE10.  IF there weren't, it would not be a preview, it would be a final release.

The purpose of the preview is NOT for you to find bugs, most of those bugs will likely be found by their testing.  The purpose of a preview is so that you can gain experience in the tool, and have something to play with html 5 against.

You're going to need to wait for at least a beta or release candidate before you should even bother relying on it to be stable.